# Image cross domain mapping

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, mapping

I have built a simple PHP/MySQL CMS on cms.mywebsite.com.

This is where I do all data entry and image uploads. The uploaded images are stored in the physical directory: `cms.mywebsite.com/uploads/images/`

On the front end I would like to be able to have all image tags src to use main domain URL (not cms. subdomain)

So ideally on mywebsite.com all image tags would look like:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/cool-img.jpg">
```

I presume I can map all images from `http://cms.mywebsite.com/uploads/images/...` to be available via `http://mywebsite.com/images/...`
but I don't know what is the best way to do it in htaccess.

hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, I do not use a redirection or rewrite.
I use linux symbolic link:

```
ln -s /path/to/cms.mywebsite.com/uploads/images /path/to/mywebsite.com/images
```

But if you prefer, you can use this `.htaccess` in `mywebsite.com/images/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://cms.mywebsite.com/uploads/images/$1   [L]
```

which redirects only the missing images in the folder

Comment: That worked perfectly - RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ http://cms.mywebsite.com/uploads/images/$1   [L]